# Написать функцию, которая получает строку и возвращает строку, состоящую из первых символов слов строки. Написать пример обращения к функции

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

char* func(char* str, char* dest, int size)
{
    int spaceCount = 0;
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
            spaceCount++;

        if (i == 0 && str[i] != ' ')
        {
            dest[index] = str[i];
            index++;

        }

        if (i > 0 && spaceCount > 0)
        {
            dest[index] = str[i + 1];
            index++;
            spaceCount = 0;
        }
    }

    dest[index] = 0;
    return dest;
}

int main()
{

    char str[255] = { 0 };
    std::cout << "Enter string " << std::endl;
    std::cin.getline(str, 255);
    int size = strlen(str) + 1;

    char* dest = new char[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        dest[i] = 0;

    dest = func(str, dest, size);
    std::cout << dest << std::endl;

    delete[] dest;

    return 0;
}
```

Можно ли решить данную задачу, используя функцию strtok?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вообще-то использовать `strtok()` для такой задачи не лучший выбор, поскольку 1) strtok необратимо изменяет исходную строку 2) способ, подобный вашему более эффективен (традиционно в таком алгоритме используется флаг `inword`, который первоначально устанавливается в 0,  при обнаружении непробельного символа устанавливается в 1, а при нахождении пробела опять ставится в 0)

Comment: Использовать new такое себе) есть куча современных методов управления памятью - умные указатели, контейнеры) забывайте про malloc, free, new, delete)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char* func( char* str)
{
    size_t index = 0, sz = strlen(str);    
    char* dest = new char[sz + 1];          
    char* p = strtok(str, " ");
    while (p) {
        dest[index++] = p[0];
        p = strtok(nullptr, " ");
    }
    dest[index] = 0;
    return dest;
}

int main() {        
    char str[255];
    std::cout << "Enter string " << std::endl;
    std::cin.getline(str, 255); 
    char* dest = func(str);
    std::cout << dest << std::endl;
    delete[] dest;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с динамической строкой результата и примерно вашим алгоритмом  выделения первых букв слов (из кода в вопросе).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *
add_chr (char *s, int c, size_t *pos, size_t *cursize)
{
  if (*pos == *cursize - 1) {
    (*cursize) *= 2;
    if (!(s = (char *)realloc(s, *cursize)))
      return 0;
  }
  s[(*pos)++] = c;

  return s;
}

int
is_word_letter (int c)
{
  return (c <= ' ' || strchr(".,'\"`!?/\\[{]}()*&^:;-+~", c)) ? 0 : 1;
}


char *
first_letters (char *src)
{
  size_t cursize = 16,
    dsti = 0;
  char *dst = (char *)malloc(cursize);
  int inword = 0,
    c;

  while ((c = (unsigned char)*src++)) {
    if (is_word_letter(c)) { 
      if (!inword)
        if (!(dst = add_chr(dst, c, &dsti, &cursize)))
          return 0;
      inword = 1;
    } else 
      inword = 0;
  }

  dst[dsti] = 0;

  return (char *)realloc(dst, dsti + 1);
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  size_t s_sz;
  char *str = 0;
  ssize_t l;

  while ((l = getline(&str, &s_sz, stdin)) > 0) {
    char *letters = first_letters(str);
    if (!letters)
      exit((puts("out of memory"), EXIT_FAILURE));

    printf("%s\n", letters);
    free(letters);
  }

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```